# How to change variable value from another module in javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am using Webpack as bundler and I can't find answer to my question anywhere.

For example, I have file index.js which contains:

```
import { Func } from './func.js'
export let foo = 'bar';

Func();
console.log(foo);
```

I have another file, let's say func.js which contains:

```
import { foo } from './index.js';
export const Func = () => { foo = 'baz' }
```

But it isn't possible to change value of variable from another module.

How do you handle such situations if I don't want to move function 'Func' to index.js?

I also know it is possible to mutate objects but using an object is not always an option.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow, in this example you're showcasing a cyclic reference which is very frowned upon, I don't understand ES6 modules very well, but I'd say that index.js tries to load `Func` before declaring foo, then `Func` doesn't find foo already loaded and loads a new index, edits that new foo (which gets discarded and forgotten), and only then your main `"index.js"` initializes its own foo with the value `'bar'`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` is a primitive. You can't change it's the value assigned to it in the other module when it's a primitive, you can only change the value `foo` has been assigned in scope of the current module.

You could always do it with functions however:

```
let foo = 'initial value';

export const getFoo = () => foo;
export const setFoo = (val) => (foo = val);
```

```
import { getFoo, setFoo } from 'someModule';

getFoo(); // initial value;

// call this when necessary
setFoo('jim');
```

```
import { getFoo } from 'someModule';

// when called after `setFoo` has been called in the other module
getFoo(); // 'jim'
```

Comment: In this case, it isn't really matters that `foo`'s value is a primitive (OP wants to reassign, not mutate its value; you wouldn't be able to reassign it even if it were an object). Otherwise, you're correct, +1